# UIImagePickerController EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, exc-bad-access

I set up my app to run like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:
                         [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    self.viewController = picker;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

After Image picker appears, I choose, for example, "Camera Roll". After that I press the back button (titled "Photos"). App crashes giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
When I enable zombie objects I receive "EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT (subcode = 0xdefe)" error with following logs. Either:

```
[UIView willRemoveSubview:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2088ea20
```

or if I proceed with image selection:

```
-[PLImageScrollView willRemoveSubview:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d82c910
```

On the other hand if I create a new project and put only stated code inside AppDelegate, code works as it should - no errors.

Now, I'm starting a new project and I will copy stuff from my previous project in order to find out what is the problem. If anyone has ideas why these errors occur, please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem. AppDelegate indirectly imported my own custom UIView category in which I (for unknown reasons) implemented *dealloc* method.

All views practically could not get deallocated properly. I deleted that dealloc method from that category and everything was allright.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring `UIImagePickerController* picker` in `AppDelegate.h` as class level variable. picker is getting deallocated after `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application`  finishes.