# Weird crash while navigating back

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

My app crashes randomly when navigating back in a `NavigationController`. Here is what I know:

- It happens randomly (sometimes, I can come back once or twice and if I reload the viewController and press "back" again it will crash)
- It happens even with an empty `ViewController` (I tried to comment out all my code in `ViewController.h` and `.m` and to remove all the outlets links)
- Nothing shows up in the debug console, only a `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` is shown in `main.m`

I spent the afternoon on this and tried everything.
I don't include code right now because I have no idea where to look. As I said, it even happens with an empty `ViewController`.

Any thoughts or similar experience ?

**EDIT:**

- Yes I tried to add an exception breakpoint
- I even tried to find some observer issues with Spark debugger.

**EDIT 2:**
Actually, the `ViewControllers` were not *that* empty. The import on an UIView category was the problem. Check my answer below.

Comment: Adding an [Exception Breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/653513) could help narrowing things up.

Comment: _I don't include code right now because I have no idea where to look._ Start with the code for popping and pushing views to the stack. Can you show us the code that's called when you go to a new view?

Comment: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS usually happens when you try to access an object that is not instantiated or has been released. Check if all the objects are retained in the previous view.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: How are you navigating? Segues (if yes what type?), pushing/poping view controllers?

Comment: Thanks for your time. @rokjarc Already tried, no exception are thrown.

Comment: @BSMP nothing special, I'm litteraly doing performSegueWithIdentifier: nothing else.

Comment: @rmaddy iOS is my domain of expertise. But this stuff nothing happened before. I know how to debug, but here nothing works.

Comment: @sunshine Yes, segue with a standard "show" type. And then the back action is called by the back button of the navigation controller

Comment: Try turning on slow animations in the simulator, to see if it causes the problem to occur more regularly. View controllers that are updated during a navigation animation (due to a timer or some other asynchronous event) can cause crashes as the view outlives it's controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some of my views were importing a custom UIView category that included a `dealloc` method. I deleted the `dealloc` method from the category and everything is fine now.

Comment: Was that your own category or some third party code? If it is third party code, tell us which one so that it is avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say exactly what could be causing it without more information, but in my experience the most common reason for an EXC_BAD_ACCESS is when someone tries to call a selector on a deallocated instance. This issue can be a lot easier to debug if you enable zombie objects.

Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics -> Enable Zombie Objects

Now instead of getting a bad access exception you should get a more helpful "message sent to deallocated instance" error (assuming that's actually the problem), along with what method was being called on which class of object.

Comment: I tried that on Friday without result. But to day I got "Message sent to deallocated instance" error. A quick search got me to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17367251/598812 wich was exactly my problem. Thanks !